# Sharepoint Chart Web Part - Dynamically Counting ListItems?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Within an aspx page I have 2 List Web Parts.  The Lists are show reports grouped by date and status e.g.

Report Date :23/02/2012 (4)
Status : Assigned (3)
Status : Closed (1)

I want to create what should be a simple graph to show per status the number of items.  X Status would be date, Y status number.  I am trying to achieve this using the Sharepoint Web Chart (under Business Data category) but it doesn't seem to expose this kind of flexibility.  Does anyone have any suggestion on how I can build this kind of chart on the fly and count the list items per category per date for charting purposes?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please answer to my queries below? 1) Whether you are trying to create chart in SharePoint? 2) You have two lists so whether you are trying to create chart using data of two lists combined? 3)According your explanation x-axis should be date and y axis should be number of items, but do you need to display status information (Assigned/Closed) also in the chart?

Comment: @sharmila. Hi, yes I am trying to create the chart directly in Sharepoint using the Chart web part.  My chart is being derived from one list.  Imagine the List contains the following fields: Report Date, Status.  All I want to do is on the X axis display the Report Date, and on the Y axis display the count for each status.  There are 5 possible statuses to choose from, but the count of statuses is  per date is not held anywhere.  This is what I need to get a handle on and understand how I can dynamically count per date the number of  statuses and display in bar chart?

Comment: You can try Visifire for SharePoint. First I suggest you to watch this video: http://www.youtube.com/embed/mSxAajlUnt4?hd=1  Next open chart designer, go to Group Data Tab and group the data according to your need. Its just a matter of 4 to 5 clicks. I'm sure you will be able to achieve your requirement. Download Link: http://www.visifire.com/download_silverlight_wpf_controls.php#sharepoint